# Replace specific line numbers using sed

Tags: sed

I use below to replace text on line numbers `29 to 32`:

```
sed -i '29,32 s/^ *#//' file
```

How can I further add line numbers i.e. line `35 to 38`, line `43` & line `45` in above command?

Comment: Might be better to use awk

   `awk 'NR > 28 && NR < 32 || NR > 34 && NR < 39 || NR == 43 || NR == 45 {#do gsub#}' file
`

Comment: @VarunM Thanks for the alternative, however I'll go with below answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GNU sed. `m` is here a label.

```
sed -i '29,32bm;35,38bm;43bm;45bm;b;:m;s/^ *#//' file
```

From `man sed`:

> `b label`: Branch to label; if label is omitted, branch to end of script.
>
> `: label`: Label for b and t commands.

Comment: Great! Works like charm.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
cat <<\! | sed 's:$:s/^ *#//:' | sed -f - -i file
29,32
35,38
43,45
!
```

Create a here-document with the line ranges you desire and pass these to a sed script that creates another sed script which is run against the desired file.

The here-document could be replaced by a file:

```
sed 's:$:s/^ *#//:' lineRangeFile | sed -f - -i file
```

Comment: Thanks @potong for alternative. I went with above solution.